# Unable to view users and groups

Tags: linux, command-line, centos, debian, fedora

I am using Centos5 running on a VMWare but whenever I choose to open the User Manager menu from System->Administration, an error message always displays

> The user database cannot be read. This problem is most likely caused
>   by a mismatch between etc/passwd and /etc/shadow or /etc/group and
>   /etc/gshadow/. The program will now exit.

I am a Linux novice and have no idea how to fix this tiny issue. ANy help is thankful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The etc/passwd contains the list of users in the system. Their passwords are stored in /etc/shadow. and their groups are there in /etc/groups. All these files  should be in sync. The order of the entries are important. Please check all the files and delete any odd entries found there.

Hope this helps..